# Creating instance of an object globally (outside the constructor or any methods)

Tags: java, singleton, global-variables

I came across this class while going through a project my senior worked on. I am trying to understand if this code will work correctly, since this appears a little fishy.

Here the `DataStore` class object is being instantiated at `global` level, I am not sure how that works? 
I understand that this is a singleton class but when will such a `global` object be created? Is it guaranteed that `mContext` passed to `DataStore` will always be non-null?

```
public class DataFetcher {

    public DatStore dataStore = new DataStore(mContext, "DATA");

    private DataFetcher() {
    }

    private static class SingletonHelper {
        private static final DataFetcher INSTANCE = new DataFetcher();
    }

    public static DataFetcher getInstance(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    // Rest of the code skipped
}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: You should add the code that shows how and when mContext is set as well.

Comment: the variable `dataStore` will be created and the object `new DataStore(mContext, "DATA");` will be instantiated each time a new instance of `DataFetcher` is createted (which is only once obviusly) right bevore the private constructor  `DataFetcher()` is invoked.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle so that means new DataStore(mContext, "DATA") will be called only when mContext receives a value right?

Comment: @varunkr: yes, that's right, as long as there is a static variable mContext in DataFetcher, which is not in your code.

Comment: Are you asking what an instance variable is?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're an educator or a student.  In neither case should code like this be encouraged.

Google has gone to [great lengths](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2743894) to [find and remove singletons](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2007/07/google-singleton-detector-released.html) from their code base.  I would not encourage students to use them.

Even if I thought a singleton was necessary, I would say this example is unnecessarily complex and opaque.  There's no need for a helper or other machinery.  This is sufficient:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() { return instance; }
}
```

I've never understood a lazy instantiated `Singleton`.  If you know it'll be used, why wait?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see, But I think I didn't get the answer to my question i.e when exactly will the DataStore object be instantiated? Will it be instantiated only after getInstance() is called? Or there is no such guarantee in which case mContext  passed to it might be null and cause problem in the DataStore class. I understand that this code is complex and may be bad. But I have not seen an object being instantiated in such a way and that is why I asked. Thanks !!

Comment: The DataStore is instantiated the moment you call "new".  What I don't see  anywhere in all that code is where you expose it to consumers.  That's why I wrote what I did: To simplify how consumers of DataStore get at it.